# Log incident when an account is locked after three failed attempts with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I want to log in the database the incident when a users account is locked. I'm using Rails3 and Devise, so I think I'll need to override some action in a Devise controller, I just don't know which controller/action and how to capture the users Id. Any tips?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the easiest approach is probably to override lock_access! from the lockable mixin (in your user model):

```
def lock_access!
  super
  # record an account lock here
end
```