# Devise: Registering log in attempts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails 3.0 project using ***devise*** and I've been requested to register in DB every succesful login and every failed attempt.

From the ***devise*** documentation I think I'd have to extend `FailureApp` but the examples are just redirecting users and not using the model at all. In **stackoverflow** I've just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956508/log-incident-when-an-account-is-locked-after-three-failed-attempts-with-devise) but it remained unanswered, which is not encouraging

Can anyone tell me if I'm correct in this approach or it can't be done this way, or if there is some easier alternative I'm missing?

(I know there is no code yet, I'm just looking for a small guidance before diving in)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying `Devise::SessionsController` to do your dirty work will do the trick.

Simply copy that file into your **app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb**

Once you've done that, just add some code to where the user successfully logs in and where he fails to log in that will do what you want.

You'll probably want to create a new model for tracking login records.

Comment: Thanks, finding how to do intercept a failed attemp was tricky but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 6):

Spent a little bit of time looking into this myself and figured someone else might find this useful.

The create action in the devise controller calls `warden.authenticate!`, which attempts to authenticate the user with the supplied params. If authentication fails then `authenticate!` will call the devise failure app, which then runs the `SessionsController#new` action. Note, any filters you have for the `create` action will not run if authentication fails.

So the solution is to add a filter after the `new` action which checks the contents of `env["warden.options"]` and takes the appropriate action.

e.g.

```
def instrument_failed_login
  instrument "failed_login.staff" if failed_login?
end

def failed_login?
  (options = env["warden.options"]) && options[:action] == "unauthenticated"
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt; this was useful. Followed the instructions here to locally implement the logging of failed logins. Also, documented the steps in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12877182/429758

Answer (score 4):

An alternative and more maintainable way of adding logging around Devise authentication is to use the [Warden Callbacks](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Callbacks) in an initializer. This is preferable because it uses the Warden API's designed for this and doesn't involve copy/pasting controller code.

```
Warden::Manager.before_failure do |env, opts|
    logger.error("opts[:scope] authentication failure: #{opts[:message]}")
end
```

You can do the same with `Warden::Manager#after_authentication` and `Warden::Manager#before_logout`.

Comment: Is it possible to access the User via this callback?