# NoMethodError in Users::Sessions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm a new developer in *ROR*. I use devise authentication for **sign_in** or **sign_up**, it works very well, but when i select data(category or sub_category) from *database* in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` i get some errors as shown bellow:

```
NoMethodError in Users::Sessions#new

Showing C:/railsapp/facepro/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #28 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #28):    

 <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li><a href="#"><%= category.category_name %></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer should not be accepted - it doesn't fix the core of the problem.

--

**Devise**

The core of your problem has *nothing* to do with Devise.

You clue is in the error itself:

```
Showing C:/railsapp/facepro/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #28
```

Devise has absolutely no bearing on the `application` `layout` - it's only for user authentication. To fix this, you need to ensure you have the `@categories` variable defined **every** time you load the application layout

--

**ApplicationController**

To do this, you'll need to declare that variable each time you load a controller action. As every controller *should* inherit from the `application` controller, the way to do this is to use the `before_action` callback in your `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` file:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :set_categories

    private

    def set_categories
        @categories = Category.all
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to guess that you haven't defined `@categories` in `Sessions#new`.

In `SessionsController` you will need something like this:

```
def new
  @categories = Category.all
  ...
end
```

Comment: when i create devise authentication it not create SessionsController .so in controller i create file sessions_controller.rb and add def new
  @categories = Category.all
  ...
end                                                                                       but it still errors

Comment: `SessionsController` comes with Devise. This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836139/rails-how-to-override-devise-sessionscontroller-to-perform-specific-tasks-when

Comment: @categories.each is called in your application.html.erb?

Comment: yes in my application.html.erb i'm select as shown bellow :           <% @categories.each do |category| %>
   <li><a href="#"><%= category.category_name %></a></li>                                    
<% end %>