# How can track the time which one user is online? With Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a **Rails** application using Devise for authenticate users but I want track the *time for users online* in the platform. I would like have a column in user table which save the time online for this user (hours, minutes..). For example, one user was online 2 hours in total, another user 15 minutes...

Does exist some gem or Devise method for this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could send an AJAX request the server every 1 second to update the 'time online'. Make sure that the server doesn't allow the request to succeed more than once per second.

Answer (score 2):

Since `DEVICE` stores `last_sign_in_at` as soon as a user login in to the account and becomes `online`.

You can do something like this.

Add a `migration` to change users table and add a field, `total_online_time`

**`rails g migration add_total_online_time_to_users total_online_time:Float`**

Add a before action callback to your application controller to check user actions:

**`before_action :set_online_time, if: proc { user_signed_in? }`**

**In this method, I will get `last_sign_in_at` and as I have current time, I will get the difference of these times and store in the `DB` as minutes and seconds.**

Again, if he login, I will add this time to old time.

**Currently I am saving the minutes and seconds. Since I can't directly add two times.**

**EDIT:**

I am saving in minutes because, if we save string or time in Database, we cannot add the last value plus the current value on the go. So it the case.

```
def set_online_time

  start_time = current_user.last_sign_in_at.to_time;
  end_time = Time.now;

  if(start_time && end_time)_
      minutes = time_diff(start_time, end_time)
      if(current_user.total_online_time)
        minutes = current_user.total_online_time + minutes
      current_user.update_attribute(:total_online_time, minutes)
  end  

end
```

HEre is the method to manipulate time:

```
private


def time_diff(start_time, end_time)
    (start_time -  end_time) / 60
end
```

**Now,  retrieve the minutes from `DB` and convert to `HH:MM:SS`**

Hhere is the method for that ,

**`Time.at(seconds).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`**

So, **`Time.at((current_user.total_online_time) * 60).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`** is yours.

**HERE IS AN EXAMPLE:**

```
time1 = Time.now   => 2017-01-27 18:01:42 +0530

time2= Time.now - 4.hours  => 2017-01-27 14:02:02 +0530

minutes = time_diff(time1,time2)  => 239.66325946553334

Time.at((minutes) * 60).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S") => "03:59:39"

So, "03:59:39" is the online time.
```

**Note:**

1) This answer keeps on incrementing the online time of the user whenever he logs in.

2) If you want only the last time, just use,

```
minutes = time_diff(start_time, end_time)
current_user.update_attribute(:total_online_time, minutes)
```

**You can also take an extra field and save current online time.**

Comment: @Jose, checked my answer? is any explanation required as far as it is concerned?

Comment: is it possible to add total online time for the day say in business hours e.g. IST morning 9 am to evening 7 pm?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add two fields to your user table: last_login_time and hours_logged. 
Whenever the user logs in, you save its time on last_login_time. And whenever the user logs out you calculate the total time spent and adds to hours_logged.

To do this you can override devise controller methods and add these tasks. This other [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837899/7219974) says more about that.

Comment: Logged in time != online time. I never log out from sites, for example.

Comment: Agree, online time does not depend on login/logout actions, but more on "period of time that the user is on the page".