# Is it possible to do Devise sign in, out, etc without any redirection whatsover?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise, but not using the Devise controllers directly because I'm performing all of the actions through a custom built GraphQL API. One issue I have, for example, is that after enabling `confirmable`, if a user tries to sign in and I call `Devise::Controllers::Helpers#sign_in` the user gets redirected to `/api/v1/users/sign_in`, which doesn't exist and it would be wrong even if it exist. Instead, I need the failure to sign in to be returned back to my code (return value, exception, whatever), so that my API can encode that response to the frontend.

How can I do that?

For example, this is my log in function:

```
def resolve(email:, password:)
  user = User.find_for_authentication(email: email)
  if user&.valid_password?(password)
    context[:sign_in].call(user)
    { current_user: user }
  else
    { errors: [{ message: 'Email or password incorrect.' }] }
  end
end
```

`context[:sign_in]` is set up in the GraphqlController by including `Devise::Controllers::Helpers` and then simply:

```
context = {
  current_user: current_user,
  sign_in: method(:sign_in),
  sign_out: method(:sign_out)
}
```

Note: I am not using [GraphqlDevise](https://github.com/graphql-devise/graphql_devise) because I don't want to use [Devise Token Auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth), I'm using cookies.

Comment: Haven't had the chance to play with graphql yet, but I found this gem https://github.com/graphql-devise/graphql_devise

Answer (score 0):

I believe passing devise's sign_in/sign_out methods via context is probably a deadend.

The suggestion in the comment to your question from @Int'l Man Of Coding Mystery is good ie you could use: https://github.com/graphql-devise/graphql_devise.

If you're not keen in introducing another dependency and figuring out how to wire everything you can perhaps go with overriding devise's SessionController.
See for some examples here: [Rails - How to override devise SessionsController to perform specific tasks when user signs in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836139/rails-how-to-override-devise-sessionscontroller-to-perform-specific-tasks-when)
(but also don't hesitate to look at the source code for the matching Devise release: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb)

Depending on your use case you might be even able to do what you need by using some of the config options - e.g. you can perhaps try to override `after_sign_in_path` etc.

Comment: I have no problem with introducing another dependency, but I'm not interested in Devise Token Auth, which is why I'm not using that gem.