# Override Devise SessionController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, overriding

I overwritten Devise sessioncontroller#create as it is in the tutorial (`SessionController < Devise::SessionController` and adding `devise_for` in routes) but the session is still made by gem. Does anyone know what to do in such a situation?

Comment: Did you put your custom controller to `routes.rb`?

Comment: In routes I add devise_for :users, controllers {sessions: 'sessions'}

Comment: check this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837899/18653817

Answer (score 0):

Now you have few problems:

- There is no such `Devise::SessionController` constant (`Devise::SessionsController` is present)
- In `devise_for :users, controllers {sessions: 'sessions'}` you doesn't use `:controllers` key and specify absent controller (sessions instead of session)
- Usually controllers are plural

How you can fix it

- Rename `SessionController < Devise::SessionController` to `SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController` (in `app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb`)
- Specify this controller in `routes.rb` as `devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'sessions'}`

[Read more](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers)