# Getting rid of DEPRECATION WARNING: env is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.0.

Tags: actionpack, ruby-on-rails-5

While migrating to Rails 5.0.0.beta1 I discovered lots of deprecation warning :

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: env is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.0. (called from XXX at YYY)
```

I've tried to get rid of that and try to find an alternative but found nothing in the actionpack changelog.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ok, so it seems that `env` method has been deprecated in ActionPack by [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/05934d24aff62d66fc62621aa38dae6456e276be).

so from now on we should user `request.env` instead of `env` in our controllers and helpers.