# How to detect a failed login attempt with the Devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I would like to detect failed login attempts and I want to avoid monkey-patching.

Initially, I thought that I can simply use the Warden `before_failure` hook:

```rb
Warden::Manager.before_failure do |env, opts|
  # failed login?
end
```

However, this doesn't work as expected - the hook is also being called when you try to access an authenticated resource while not being authenticated - not just a failed login attempt specifically.

I've found that Devise::SessionsController passes a `recall` key to Warden [during authentication](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/ec0674523e7909579a5a008f16fb9fe0c3a71712/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L48). It means that the code below would technically work:

```rb
Warden::Manager.before_failure do |env, opts|
  next unless opts.key?(:recall)

  # failed login attempt!
end
```

However, this doesn't seem like an "official" solution and I can't find any suggestions on how to handle this in the Devise docs. How should I solve this without monkey-patching the SessionsController?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Devise: Registering log in attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170324/devise-registering-log-in-attempts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the before_failure method, just need check if there were any parameters passed.  If there weren't -- it's not a failed attempt. Change `:user` to whatever your model is.

```
 Warden::Manager.before_failure do |env, opts|
    email = env["action_dispatch.request.request_parameters"][:user] &&
            env["action_dispatch.request.request_parameters"][:user][:email]

    unless email.blank?
      ## login failed - do something
    end
   
  end
```